# standard error in a dice betting game

Tags: statistics

I am trying to work through example 22-4 (which changes slightly each time):
http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/standardError.htm#SE_of_RV

You pay \$2 to roll a fair pair of dice. You win \$3 if you roll doubles. The SE of your net winnings after nine plays of the game is __?

The given solution uses an affine transformation of the standard error in the following way:

$Y= -18+3X$

$SE(X)=\sqrt{np(1-p)}=\sqrt{9\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}}= 1.118$

$SE(Y)=|3|SE(X)=3.354$

My failed approach was to try to compute the SE directly for one play and then use the affine transform to get the SE for 9 plays, however I'm not sure why this doesn't work:

$E(X) = x_0P(X=x_0)+x_1P(X=x_1)= -2(5/6)+3(1/6)=-7/6$

$SE(X) = \sqrt{P(X=x_0)(x_0 - E(X))^2+P(X=x_1)(x_1 - E(X))^2}=\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}(-2+\frac{7}{6})^2+\frac{1}{6}(3+\frac{7}{6})^2}= 1.863$

Comment: Exercise 22-4 looks slight different to me, and gives the solution if you click

Comment: The SE for $9$ is $\sqrt{9}$ times the SE for one. No affine transformation involved. Where affine transformation (gee, what's with these fancy terms, I thought statisticians were down to earth) is involved is when you express your net gain on one throw in terms of the rv $W$ which is $1$ if you get a double and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Your $X$ is the expectation of one game and assumes the $\$2$ is refunded if you get doubles as well as the $\$3$.  Their $X$ is for all $9$ games and does not include the refund of your stake when you win.  So your $E(X)$ should be $-9/6$ to match them.

Comment: Using X as the random variable and summing over the possible outcomes of x (lose \$2 or win \$3), I was trying to calculate SE with $\sum \limits_{x}^{x \epsilon{\{-2,3\}}}\sqrt{P(X=x)(x-E(X)^2)}$, which seems to be the approach used in example 22-3. I now see that multiplying SE by $\sqrt{n}$ should give me the SE for n trials. Is this approach correct? If so, maybe I've made a dumb arithmetic mistake somewhere.